# Magento registration customer from - Remove filed asterisk

Tags: magento2

registration form shows one of the field as required, but it is not required, how remove the asterisk.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`*` is showing by class `required`.
You need to remove `required` class from input field and `*` will get remove as well.

[image]

See attached screen shot for reference

Comment: it is not html, it is dynamic PHP,

        <input type="file" id="trade_license" name="trade_license" class="input-file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf" data-validate="{required:false, 'validate-filesize':true, 'validate-fileextensions':true}"/>

Answer (score 0):

What I can see is from the screenshot you shared, this is not magento's default registration page it is some custom module customisation or overrided in your custom theme.

In order to remove **asterisk**, first you need to find where is this page coming from and after that override that file properly in your custom theme or custom module, then you can remove **require** class from the fields that you don't want to be required.

Comment: Hello, I already changed to false and upgrade, but it is still there.

Comment: <input type="file" id="trade_license" name="trade_license" class="input-file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf" data-validate="{required:false, 'validate-filesize':true, 'validate-fileextensions':true}"/>

Comment: As you shared your input field, you'll find div tag above this and in that div tag you'll find css class for the required, remove that and flush your cache. if you want reference then open vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml and you'll see <div class="field required"> this in the file